# When are JVM arguments evaluated into system properties?

Tags: java, security, jvm, bouncycastle, jvm-arguments

I have an application which is started with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` but which does not actually show any debug logging.  This property is evaluated in a static block in `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` as shown below

```
    static {
        String s = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
            new GetPropertyAction("javax.net.debug", "")).toLowerCase(
                                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
        DEBUG = s.contains("all") || s.contains("ssl");
    }
```

Is there any possibility that this static block evaluates the property value before the JVM arg sets the value?  What's peculiar about this is that it only happens when a certain `Provider` is set on the classpath (along with other associated jar files), namely the BouncyCastle FIPS Provider.  I'm wondering if somehow this library introduces a race condition or it prevents debug logging of TLS/SSL completely.

I assumed that passing this as a JVM arg would ensure the earliest possible setting of this property.  When are these evaluated and is it possible this is a race condition or is this a 'feature' of the bc-fips provider jar?

Comment: Try to create a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise the question is too abstract. It's unlikely the code is executed before the property is set. Setting system properties is one of the first things JVM does during initialization.

Comment: It appears from the discussion in the issue [Logging of TLS handshake details #742](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/742) that BouncyCastle does not respect that system property. I couldn't find any evidence of it changing the value of that property. I don't know why your code above doesn't see it set.

Comment: It’s rather the opposite. Between the initial setting by the JVM and the execution of this class initializer, a lot of other things may happen, including the possibility that some code overwrites this system property.